# Modify value inside a node C#

Tags: c#, xml

s.xml is the file with below contents

```
*<scale-tolerance>80
            <description>Tolerance</description>
</scale-tolerance>*
```

In the above snippet, I intend to modify the value of 80

I tried the below code

```
XmlDocument xmlDocSecurityConfig = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocSecurityConfig.Load(/*path to the file s.xml*/);
xmlDocSecurityConfig.SelectSingleNode("/scale-tolerance").Innertext = "166";
xmlDocSecurityConfig.Save(securityFilePath);
```

Problem is that the code just not replaces **80** with 166
Instead replaces `**80 <description>Tolerance</description>**` with 166.

Any suggestions on how to modify only the value 80 with 166 ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I could find the answer and below is the resolution

```
XmlDocument xmlDocSecurityConfig = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocSecurityConfig.Load(/*path to the file s.xml*/);
xmlDocSecurityConfig.SelectSingleNode("/security/smart-scale/security-scale-scanner-scale-tolerance").FirstChild.Value = "166";
xmlDocSecurityConfig.Save(securityFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. You need to replace `InnerXml` of `scale-tolerance` node with new value and `OuterXml` of `description` node:

```
XmlNode st = xmlDocSecurityConfig.SelectSingleNode("scale-tolerance");
XmlNode de = st.SelectSingleNode("description");
st.InnerXml = "166" + de.OuterXml;
```

Good luck!